# Redirecting non www to www, SSL ON

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, amazon-ec2

I've installed apache on AWS ec2 instance and I'm having a problem redirecting "non www" to "www" when using https.

```
   http://example.com --> https://www.example.com WORKS
   http://www.example.com --> https://www.example.com WORKS 
   https://www.example.com --> https://www.example.com WORKS 
   https://example.com --> https://example.com DOESN'T REDIRECT to www.*
```

I'd like to fix it using VirtualHost (not .htaccess), and this is what I have currently in my httpd.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html 
        ServerName example.com 
        ServerAlias www.example.com 

 Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/" 
</VirtualHost>
```

This is in httpd-le-ssl.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
        ServerName "example.com"
        ServerAlias "www.example.com"
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

P.S I have used Let's Encrypt for SSL certificate. I'm mentioning this in case there are some other ".conf" files that might have a conflicting configuration with what I have in httpd.conf file.

Comment: As I already explained in a comment [on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66499976/redirecting-non-www-to-www-ssl-on): *"... you would also need a config for https:// (port 443, with certificate setup) and **the redirect would need to be setup in this other config** "*. While you know show the config for port 443 __the redirect you have for port 80 is obviously not in the config for port 443__.

Comment: I tried to add redirect as I did for `http:// ` but it still doesn't work. That's why I'm asking if someone knows how to do it.

Comment: *"I tried to add redirect as I did for http://  but it still doesn't work"* - then please  add what you tried to your question and also explain in detail what happens instead of just "doesn't work".

Comment: Also, why do you quote the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` and `DocumentRoot` in the config for port 443? You don't do this for port 80. I'm not sure if this will even work.